# C++- How to return first highest element inserted in vector of pair of integer?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I have vector of pair int and string like this `vector<pair<int, string> >`.

I have input like this:

```
1 mark,
3 Andrew,
2 mark,
3 mark
```

Then I can sort it...
I want to return string with highest int value which is inserted first in this case andrew.

This problem is from codeforces beta round #2

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++ questions!

Comment: If you can sort it, you can get the element from `v` by using `v.back()`. Could you provide an example of the actual problem?

Comment: You would have to do a stable sort to not change the insertion order when the int is the same.

Comment: As I have explained I want to return a string with highest value of int but when I sort it I get last inserted string which is mark in this case.....I want to get first inserted element with highest value of int in this case Andrew..

Comment: You have yet to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: This problem is from codeforces beta round#2 I'm just beginner ...

Comment: Jens's answer is cool...I appreciate to all who have answered this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, sort the vector using stable sort w.r.t to the integer value. Then, use `lower_bound` to search the first element with the maximum integer value. For a `vector v`, the code would look like:

```
bool cmpFirst(std::pair<int, std::string> const& x, 
              std::pair<int, std::string> const& y)
{
    return x.first < y.first;
}

std::stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmpFirst);
auto firstMaxString = std::lower_bound( v.begin(), v.end(), 
                                        v.back().first, 
                                        cmpFirst)->second;
```

If you need to do it only once, scanning the vector is faster because it is an O(n) operation, while sorting is O(n log n). See the answer from Open Kastle for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::max_element` with a lambda express to search a range for the maximum element using your specific comparison criteria.  In this case you define your comparison function to compare only the `int` value in the pair:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> myList = { ... };

auto find = std::max_element(begin(myList), end(myList),
    [](const std::pair<int, std::string>& pairA, const std::pair<int, std::string>& pairB)
    {
        return pairA.first < pairB.first;
    }
);

std::string maximumString = find->second;
```

Comment: But this will return string with highest int value which is inserted FIRST???

Comment: In this example mark and Andrew has highest int value but Andrew is inserted first so this will return Andrew??

Comment: @Shreyas Shirwadkar Yes, `std::max_element` is guaranteed to return the first maximum element in the range if there are multiple maximum elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort it, then you can get either the first element, if you sorted it descenent, or the last element, if you sorted it ascendent.

But if you don't want to sort it, you can go throughout the vector, and at every step checking for the highest int, and memorize the string:

```
maxInt = array[0]; //int
maxString = array[0].String;
for (i=1;i<arrayLength;i++){
      if (array[i] > maxInt) {
             maxInt = array[i];
             maxString = array[i].String;
      } 
}
```

And then you can simply print out the maxString.